# Dynamically load _gallery_ (not album) in SlideShowPro using SWFObject

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, actionscript-3, slideshow

I have been successful in dynamically loading an *album* in SSP before, but using SSP Standalone. I did it like this:

```
var flashvars = {
    xmlFilePath: "http://site.com/ssp_director/images.php?album=5"
}
```

What I'm looking to do now, though, is dynamically load a *gallery* when the page loads, using text entered in the javascript, or flashvars I'd assume. I'm using ActionScript 3 with this, so I'm not sure if I have to do something to the SSP instance in Flash. I'm not very good with AS3, so following advice or tutorials is about all I can muster. I'm also using SSP Director, so my gallery XML URLs would be similar to above in the example code.

I'd be elated if this is possible, otherwise I will have to find an alternative solution. Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to get it to work:

Using this article only to edit my fla/swf file: http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPfl/C-DynamicallyAssignXML

And then putting this in my SWFObject code:

```
var flashvars = {
    xmlfile: "http://site.com/images.php?gallery=2",
    xmlfiletype: "Director"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("slideshow.swf", "slideshow", "640", "634", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading `FlashVars` in **AS3** is not as simple as it used to be in AS2. Here's some code that will do this:

```
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
var fvars = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

var xmlFilePath="http://site.com/ssp_director/images.php?album="+fvars.albumid;
```

Assuming that you'll have a `flashvars` variable named `albumid` passed in the `object/embed` tag.

Comment: I'm using SWFObject, so I don't have an object/embed tag. Is there a way to do it with SWFObject?

Comment: Sure! you have to use this: so.addVariable("variable1", "value1");